# AWS CodeBuild fails for golang source with sub-packages

Tags: go, aws-codebuild

When I attempt to build my golang project using CodeBuild golang image 1.10, it fails, unable to find the subpackages. Some background:

The application is organized as follows:

```
/go/src/company/app
/go/src/company/app/sub1
/go/src/company/app/sub2
etc...
```

This builds fine on my dev machine. However, when pulled by codebuild it is pulled into a different directory (`/codebuild/output/srcNNN/src/<some path>`) where `<some path>` varies according to what triggers the build.

I originally got it working by copying the code from where it is pulled to the the golang directory (`/codebuild/output/srcNNN`), but since the CodeBuild environment variable for the `GOPATH` directory inserts /go: (`/go:/codebuild/output/srcNNN`) in the front, I used an observed number of ../../... to copy. However, this is ugly and failed as soon as I triggered the build a different way.

My question is whether there is a good way to get this working? My next idea is to apply string manipulation to the observed path and copy there for (hopefully) more reliability. But that will only work as long as the `GOPATH` conforms to my assumptions.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

---

Clarification:
When importing packages in the code, external packages are imported as follows:

```
import (
    "context"
    ...
}
```

Subpackages are not explicitly imported, but found when code is deployed as shown above (`/go/src/company/app`). However, AWS CodeBuild doesn't bring in the code this way.

Comment: Can you please show how do you import your packages in the code?

Comment: Not expert on CodeBuild, but had similar issues with other AWS build system for go. I believe if you just vendor your dependencies into /go/src/company/app/vendor sub-directory, it should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, but if I understand you correctly, our own subpackages are already so vendor'ed, but are not found because the code is actually brought into (to put it in your terms)  /go/src/<some path>/company/app/vendor. So, when go looks in /go/src/app/vendor it is not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See **Update** below for a complete answer if you are on golang 1.11 or higher... We no longer use my initial work around.

I was able to get *an* answer working. I'll post it here in case it is helpful to others, but it relies on observed behavior in AWS CodeBuild to work, so I don't think it is ideal.

In my buildspec.yaml I am able to get the build to work by:

1. Getting `${THEGOPATH}` from `${GOPATH}` by removing the "/go:" from the beginning
2. Copying all the code to the `${THEGOPATH}/src/<app path>`
3. Copying other repositories to `${THEGOPATH}/src/<other app path>`
4. Importing external dependencies as normal (in our case, `go get ./...` or explicit)
5. Building and forcing the output name (when launched from CodeBuild it used a different directory name)

The buildspec.yaml looks something like the following:

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo GOPATH - $GOPATH
      - export THEGOPATH=`echo $GOPATH | cut -c 5-`
      - echo THEGOPATH = $THEGOPATH
      - mkdir -p ${THEGOPATH}/src/company/app1
      - mkdir -p  ${THEGOPATH}/src/company/other_repository_dependency
      - echo Copy source files to go root
      - cp -a ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}/. ${THEGOPATH}/src/company/app1/${PACKAGE}
      - cp -a ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_other_dep}/. ${THEGOPATH}/src/app/other_repository_dependecy/.
      - ls ${THEGOPATH}/src/
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Getting packages
      - go get ./...
      - echo DOING THE BUILD
      - go build -ldflags "<some flags>" -o "appname"
      - go test ./...
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - ls -al
      - pwd
artifacts:
  files:
    - appname
```

---

**Update -- Better fix**
Today we attempted to build with go modules (available since 1.11) see [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) for an explanation of go modules.

Using go modules we defined the current source module app1 as `company-name.com` in the go.mod file like this:

```
module company-name.com/app1

go 1.12
require (
   ... *for example*
   github.com/golang/mock v1.3.1
   github.com/google/btree v1.0.0 // indirect
   github.com/google/go-cmp v0.3.0
   ... *etc*
```

We even reference our external files this way (though you'll need to figure out how to authenticate with your git repository. We used the credential helper built into the buildspec for https authentication). So, our import blocks look something like this now:

```golang
     import ( 
       "company-name.com/app1/subpackage1"
       abbrev "company-name.com/app1/subpackage2"
       "company-name.com/externalpkg"  // In another private git repo of ours
       ... //etc
     )
     ... //golang source follows here*
```

Finally, we added the following environment variable to the buildspec:

```
  variables:
    GO111MODULE: "on"
    git-credential-helper: yes
```

These ensured that modules worked in the path (thanks amwill04 for reminding me of my omission) and allowed the credentials for our Git repository to get setup properly.

In doing this we accomplished everything we needed:

1. By changing our references to the go module we could easily reference the subpackages as such
2. We were able to lock the version of all our dependencies
3. By implementing a simple server at company-name.com, we could reference other private modules from our application

Comment: Having the same problem. Is this still the solution you're using, or did you find something more long-term sustainable?

Comment: We are still using this.

Comment: Just got anyone coming across this answer I needed to put `GO111MODULE=on` in front of `go build`. I think this is due to the fact you are running the command inside `GOPATH` and it therefore turns off modules.

Comment: Great point! Answer updated to include these bits I omitted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach that I took.

```
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    PACKAGE: "github.com/rhyselsmore/foo"

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      # AWS Codebuild Go images use /go for the $GOPATH so let's copy our
      # application source code into that directory structure.
      - mkdir -p "/go/src/$(dirname ${PACKAGE})"
      - ln -s "${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}" "/go/src/${PACKAGE}"
      - # Make sure we're in the package directort within our GOPATH
      - cd "/go/src/${PACKAGE}"
```

Now assuming that the PACKAGE variable is the root of your repository that you are building, we can issue go commands. Lets break it down line-by-line.

```
- mkdir -p "/go/src/$(dirname ${PACKAGE})"
```

This creates a new directory within the GOPATH for your package.

```
- ln -s "${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}" "/go/src/${PACKAGE}"
```

This creates a symbolic link from the root of your CodeBuild project to your Go package.

```
- cd "/go/src/${PACKAGE}"
```

This primes the rest of your Codebuild operations to take place in the CWD of your Go package.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just today we finally tried go modules, which I believe is a more correct answer (though I believe this works fine). Please see my answer above if you are using 1.11 or later. Also, note that the "/go" directory being the GOPATH is a current observed behavior that AWS has not committed to continuing to use. Parsing the GOPATH environment variable would be more future proof IMHO.

Comment: We are also using Go modules - left the answer just in case anyone is pinned to the older versions of Go (like you were in your original answer). I understand that AWS have not committed to it, but it is hardcoded into their Docker images for versions up until now. When using modules, the above answer can also be modified to symlink your codebase outside of the $GOPATH, which is important as Codebuild makes as your source directory the $GOPATH with the new Golang buildspec runtime directives - meaning modules won't work correctly.